# Query to collect last occurrence of a character in a string (SQL Progress OpenEdge)

Tags: sql, substring, openedge, locate

I need to pick out some string from a string that varies in length.
The end result is to pick out the id number, contained in brackets, from a string.

An example of the data is:

```
Jones (4)
Smith (Deceased) (100)
```

The result from the above example would need to be:

```
4
100
```

Ideally I want a query that will find the start position of the last open bracket and pick up the data from that point onwards, because the id number, contained in brackets, is always at the end.

Unfortunately, `REVERSE`, `CHARINDEX` and `PATINDEX` are not available in `OpenEdge` SQL functions so I cannot use those.

`INSTR(contact_data,'(',1,2)` gives me the start point, but requires me to provide the nth occurrence - which is a variable because some data contains 1 bracket, some contain more.

I have tried to introduce a variable into occurrences, but it errors - please see below and please help if you can!

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(PROCLAIM,'
SELECT a.contact_data,
INSTR(a.contact_data,''('',1,a.bracket_occurrences) AS searching_for_start_point,    SUBSTRING(a.contact_data,LOCATE(''('',a.contact_data,1)+1,LENGTH(a.contact_data)-LOCATE(''('',a.contact_data,1)-1) AS contact_id
FROM(
SELECT contact_data,
CAST(LENGTH(contact_data) - LENGTH(REPLACE(contact_data,''('','''')) AS INT) AS bracket_occurrences
FROM PUB.contacts
) AS a
')
```

Unfortunately, I only have access to a very limited set of SQL commands as I am using `Progress` `OpenEdge`.

Below is a list of the SQL commands/functions available to me:

```
ABS,  ACOS,  ADD_MONTHS,  ASCII,  ASIN,  ATAN,  ATAN2,  AVG,  CASE,  CAST,  
CDC_get_changed_columns,  CDC_is_column_changed,  CEILING,  CHAR,  CHR,              
COALESCE,  CONCAT,  CONVERT (ODBC compatible),  CONVERT (Progress extension),  
COS,  COUNT,  CURDATE,  CURTIME,  CURRVAL,  DATABASE,  DAYNAME,  DAYOFMONTH,  
DAYOFWEEK,  DAYOFYEAR,  DB_NAME,  DECODE,  DEGREES,  EXP,  FLOOR,  GREATEST,  
HOUR,  IFNULL,  INITCAP,  INSERT,  INSTR,  LAST_DAY,  LCASE,  LEAST,  LEFT,  
LENGTH,  LOCATE,  LOG10,  LOWER,  LPAD,  LTRIM,  MAX,  MIN,  MINUTE,  MOD,  
MONTH,  MONTHNAME,  MONTHS_BETWEEN,  NEXT_DAY,  NEXTVAL,  NOW,  NULLIF,  NVL,  
PI,  POWER,  PREFIX,  PRO_ARR_DESCAPE function,  PRO_ARR_ESCAPE function,  
PRO_ELEMENT function,  QUARTER,  RADIANS,  RAND,  REPEAT,  REPLACE,  RIGHT,  
ROUND,  ROWID,  RPAD,  RTRIM,  SECOND,  SIGN,  SIN,  SQRT,  SUBSTR,  SUBSTRING 
(ODBC compatible),  SUFFIX,  SUM,  SYSDATE,  SYSTIME,  SYSTIMESTAMP,  TAN,  
TO_CHAR,  TO_DATE,  TO_NUMBER,  TO_TIME,  TO_TIMESTAMP,  TRANSLATE,  UCASE,  
UPPER,  USER,  WEEK,  YEAR
```

Comment: What length can the ID be? If not all too long a hairy COALESCE could be used in combination with LEAST to find the opening bracket working from the length backwards.

Comment: You said you're using Progress OpenEdge. Can you use the OpenEdge ABL commands?

Comment: I'm not sure what ABL commands are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or - revisiting INSTR (I rarely use SQL, so this is a learning experience):

```
select 
  contact_data, 
  rtrim(
    substring (
      contact_data,
      greatest( 
        instr( contact_data, '(', 1, 1 ), 
        instr( contact_data, '(', 1, 2 ), 
        instr( contact_data, '(', 1, 3 ) 
      ) + 1
    ), 
    ')'
  )
from pub.contacts
```

Once again, expand the instr's to match your requirements and beware of the edge cases (no ID in brackets).

Comment: Thank you so much.  All of your suggestions work really well.  I think I'll go with the last one, using GREATEST and I'll probably add in a few more INSTR's to make sure I cover lots of possibilities.  I should be alright with regards to the ID as it is always bracketed. Amazing!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  contact_data, 
  rtrim( 
    ltrim( 
      lower( contact_data ), 
      'abcdefghijlmnopqrstuvwxyz( )' 
    ), 
    ')'
  )
from pub.contacts
```

Rather hairy and bound to give trouble. You may need to expand the trimmed characters, this was just enough for your examples. Also if the text prior to the ID contains a number, it will break.

In ABL, R-INDEX would easily tackle the problem, the SQL syntax however is missing some string manipulation functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  contact_data, 
  rtrim(
    substring (
      contact_data,
      case
        when substring( contact_data, length( contact_data ) - 2, 1 ) = '(' then length( contact_data ) -1 
        when substring( contact_data, length( contact_data ) - 3, 1 ) = '(' then length( contact_data ) -2
        when substring( contact_data, length( contact_data ) - 4, 1 ) = '(' then length( contact_data ) -3
        when substring( contact_data, length( contact_data ) - 5, 1 ) = '(' then length( contact_data ) -4
        when substring( contact_data, length( contact_data ) - 6, 1 ) = '(' then length( contact_data ) -5
        when substring( contact_data, length( contact_data ) - 7, 1 ) = '(' then length( contact_data ) -6
        when substring( contact_data, length( contact_data ) - 8, 1 ) = '(' then length( contact_data ) -7
        else -1
      end
    ), 
    ')'
  )
from pub.contacts
```

Or you can extend this abomination :-)